# UTF-8 STDIN+STDOUT with Python ArgParse on "OS X"

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, osx-lion, argparse

The [argparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) shows an approach to file arguments defaulting to stdin/stdout, with the text encoding defaulting to utf-8

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
...                     default=sys.stdin)
>>> parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
...                     default=sys.stdout)
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(infile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' encoding='UTF-8'>,
          outfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```

On this OS X (10.7.5) system, however, this code is yielding `<stdin> <stdout>` with an ascii codec. If my output stream includes, for example, Chinese or Scandinavian characters, they will display fine on the terminal, but if I redirect the stdout to a file, an ascii codec error is tripped. Has anyone found a route around this ?

(Writing utf-8 files directly from the Python code is not a problem – I'm using `codecs.open(str_path, "w", 'UTF-8')`)

Comment: Should have mentioned that I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the Python 3 docs. Try here for [Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html).

Also, your app may need to call [setlocale()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/locale.html).

Comment: Please include more than just a link to the appropriate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the correct documentation. Have tried setlocale() but I wonder if that is the right direction ? Local date/monetary issues don't really impinge, and my UTF-8 streams often include text in various languages, unrelated to the user locale. The goal seems to be a deeper-level setting of the codec away from an ascii default to UTF-8